# Cannot Add 'AddOn Domain' in cPanel

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, multiple-domains, addon-domain

Adding AddOn Domain throws an error:

`... add one of its nameservers to /etc/ips.remotedns and make the proper A entries on that remote nameserver.`

I tried this link ["Setting up Nameserver DNS Using cPanel/WebHost Manager"](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8467/setting-up-nameserver-dns-using-cpanelwebhost-manager?pc_split_value=2&countrysite=pk/) but i don't know why this error remains.

Your answers will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This means that your domain is using remote nameservers and you are trying to add it on cPanel. Please make the change in tweak settings of WHM which will allow you to add remote domains.

Comment: This helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply solve this error from your WHM panel.

There is an option called “**Allow Remote Domains**” in **WHM tweak settings**. Switch ON the option “**Allow Remote Domains**” to add new Addon domains that having name servers other than your server. Follow these steps to enable it.

```
Login to WHM >> Home >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings >> Find "Allow Remote Domains" option under Domain group and turn ON it >> then SAVE.
```

source: http://crybit.com/error-while-adding-an-addon-domain-in-cpanel/

Comment: This answer is more specific since it clearly provide the details on how to do it.